# Google SDK for Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api, snowboy, snips

Is there any other tools available to customize the Wake Word of goolge assistent, I am tring to build the customized perrsonal assistent using Raspberry pi,

NOTE: the snowbot and snips are no longer in use, kindly let me know any other tools if we have to do the same kind of word.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.